# AudioQueueGetProperty return -50

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Here is the lines of code:

The Audio Stream Basic Description is

```
recordFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC;
recordFormat.mChannelsPerFrame   = 2;


OSStatus oss=AudioQueueGetProperty(queue, kAudioConverterCurrentOutputStreamDescription,
                                       &recordFormat, &size);
```

It keeps return OSStatus as -50, what does it means?

Thanks
Zahi

Comment: One or more parameters passed to a function where not valid.

Comment: Post a bit more code leading up to this call please.

Comment: If they find a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611215/general-param-error-retrieving-record-format-with-audioqueuegetproperty), it may help you as well. Regards