# General param error retrieving record format with AudioQueueGetProperty

Tags: iphone, ios, core-audio

I am getting a -50 (general param error) from a call to AudioQueueGetProperty. Please help me as it has been several months since I've touched XCode and any iPhone work. This is likely a simple goof on my behalf but I cannot resolve it. My code leading to the -50:

```
//Setup format
AudioStreamBasicDescription recordFormat;
memset(&recordFormat, 0, sizeof(recordFormat));
recordFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC;
recordFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
CCGetDefaultInputDeviceSampleRate(&recordFormat.mSampleRate);
UInt32 propSize = sizeof(recordFormat);
AQ(AudioFormatGetProperty(kAudioFormatProperty_FormatInfo, 0, NULL,
                                  &propSize, &recordFormat), 
           "AudioFormatGetProperty throws unexpected errors.");

//Setup Queue
//listing 4.8-4.9
AudioQueueRef theQueue = {0};
self->queue = theQueue;
AQ(AudioQueueNewInput(&recordFormat, CCAudioRecordingCallback, 
                              self, NULL, NULL, 0, &self->queue),
           "AudioQueueNewInput throws unexpected errors.");
UInt32 size = sizeof(recordFormat);
AQ(AudioQueueGetProperty(self->queue,
                                 kAudioConverterCurrentOutputStreamDescription, 
                                 &recordFormat, 
                                 &size), 
           "Getting audio property kAudioConverterCurrentOutputStreamDescription throws unexpected errors.");
```

I have verified that I have a valid queue just as I make the call to AudioQueueGetProperty. I've tried both ways of passing the queue "self->queue", and "self.queue" and they both result in the same error. The queue is defined as follows:

```
@interface CCAudioRecorder()
//...
@property (nonatomic, assign) AudioQueueRef queue;
//...

@end

@implementation CCAudioRecorder
@synthesize queue;
```

AQ is a #def:

```
#define AQ(expr, msg) if(nil!=CheckError((expr), msg)) [NSException raise:@"AudioException" format:@"Unexpected exception occured."];
```

Which resolves to the following error checking function:

```
static NSString* CheckError(OSStatus error, const char* operation)
{
    if (noErr == error) return nil;

    NSString *errorMessage = nil;
    char errorString[20];
    //See if it appears to be a 4-char code
    *(UInt32 *)(errorString+1) = CFSwapInt32HostToBig(error);
    if ( isprint(errorString[1]) && isprint(errorString[2]) 
        && isprint(errorString[3]) && isprint(errorString[4]) ) 
    {
        errorString[0] = errorString[5] = '\'';
        errorString[6] = '\0';
    } else {
        sprintf(errorString, "%d", (int)error);
    }
    errorMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                    @"Audio Error: %@ (%@)\n", 
                    [NSString stringWithUTF8String:operation], 
                    [NSString stringWithUTF8String:errorString]];
    NSLog(@"%@", errorMessage);
    return errorMessage;
}
```

I've also tried calling AudioFormatGetProperty on a queue created with a local variable, avoiding the class instance level iVar and  still get the same error:

```
AudioQueueRef theQueue = {0};
AQ(AudioQueueNewInput(&recordFormat, CCAudioRecordingCallback, 
                              self, NULL, NULL, 0, &theQueue),
           "AudioQueueNewInput throws unexpected errors.");
UInt32 size = sizeof(recordFormat);
AQ(AudioQueueGetProperty(theQueue,
                                 kAudioConverterCurrentOutputStreamDescription, 
                                 &recordFormat, 
                                 &size), 
           "Getting audio property kAudioConverterCurrentOutputStreamDescription throws unexpected errors.");
```

** Update **
I have the following code which works on the simulator and not on the device. (I have not cross referenced it with what I posted earlier but I believe it's either similar or the exact.)

```
AudioQueueRef theQueue = {0};
self->queue = theQueue;
AQ(AudioQueueNewInput(&recordFormat, CCAudioRecordingCallback, 
                              self, NULL, NULL, 0, &self->queue),
           "AudioQueueNewInput throws unexpected errors.");
UInt32 size = sizeof(recordFormat);
AQ(AudioQueueGetProperty(self->queue, 
                                 kAudioConverterCurrentOutputStreamDescription, 
                                 &recordFormat, 
                                 &size), 
           "Getting audio property kAudioConverterCurrentOutputStreamDescription throws unexpected errors.");
```

Running it on device I get a crash in the same spot with error -50 general param error. My device is an iPhone 4S running iOS6 I'm working with XCode 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

You are following the code from the [learning core audio](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321636848) book right? Chapter 4 about implementing a recorder? I noticed a difference between your code and the book's code, in the book they simply initialize the Queue and use it as is:

```
AudioQueueRef queue = {0};
UInt32 size = sizeof(recordFormat);
CheckError(AudioQueueGetProperty(queue, kAudioConverterCurrentOutputStreamDescription,
                                 &recordFormat, &size), "couldn't get queue's format");
```

I'm not sure why you're throwing `self` in the mix. But that's definitely what's causing your bug. If all fails simply download the complete code for that chapter [here](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0321636848) and see where you can identify your mistake.

Comment: You got me! :) Yes, I'm following learning core audio and I'm threw self in there as a means of caching the queue in an iVar to be used in other methods. I'm trying to implement and audio player object using more of an O/O style.

Comment: I've updated my post, trying to use the local queue directly and I still get the error. I must be missing something, or is this all changed in iOS6? I have not yet read docs on iOS6 but I've recently updated my SDK and hardware.

Comment: just updated my post. I can get this working on the simulator but it crashes on device.

Comment: @Cliff tell you what.. why don't you throw your code unto a github project so that I can download it and test it against my XCode 4.3.. i'll see what I can do

Comment: @Abdullah Thanx, I'm still working on figuring this out. You can grab the example code from the book (chapter 4) and try running it on device. I believe it works on the simulator because it's designed for desktop. There are some API differences on the device that I haven't quite figured out. It's a weekend project.

Comment: @Cliff oh.. my bad.. well yeah definitely there are differences between desktop stuff and iPhone stuff.. some OSX API's are *not* included in iOS.. if you're wondering why, you may wanna check out chapter 10 in the book (core audio and iOS).. it talks about that part.. also on a side note.. one important difference to keep your eye on is how to read the data from your iPod library on your iphone.. these can *only* be accessed via AVAssetReader..